# Magento top link cart is cached by varnish

Tags: magento, varnish

I am using Varnish to enhance performance on my Magento store.
My problem is it that Varnish is caching the top links number of items in Cart.

I was thinking to use a Ajax call after page loading, not sure how to implement,
suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this via ajax, here's one possible approach:

Backend work:

1. For each action which modifies the number of items in the cart, observe the event and fire a method that will update a cookie on the client with necessary data you need. You can do something simple and store a JSON structure: `{"cartItem": 2, "isLoggedIn": false}`. **Some** events to observe:

   1. controller_action_postdispatch_checkout
   2. controller_action_postdispatch_customer
   3. checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
2. Create a controller/action that will return the exact same data structure (as well as set the cookie while its at it).

Frontend work:

1. On DOM ready your code should look for the cookie set in the backend. If it doesn't exist, make an ajax request to the controller to fetch it.
2. Once it has the necessary data, update the values in the DOM as necessary

You'll want to make sure you listen to the all the necessary events. Using the cookie will help speed things up on the client side and reduces the number of HTTP requests the browser needs to make.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but this is not working, Varnish is caching my ajax call, and returning the same data every time. can I exclude from varnish my ajax controller? any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: @ShuanF You need to exclude the URL from being cached in your VCL config. Another option might be to make the request method POST, assuming you've configured varnish not to cache that request method.